# Replace coded text by unicode text in Vietnamese

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, decoding

I have a csv file saved under the name as [sample.csv](https://github.com/dungnguyen2/asking/blob/main/sample.csv) as follows:

```
No,duong
1, Ðu<U+1EDD>ng ÐT 605
2, Ðu<U+1EDD>ng Nam K<U+1EF3> Kh<U+1EDF>i Nghia
3, Ðu<U+1EDD>ng Duy Tân
```

I have another csv file named [viscii.csv](https://github.com/dungnguyen2/asking/blob/main/viscii.csv) containing the code of characters:

```
key, value
<U+1EDD>,ờ
<U+1EF3>,ỳ
<U+1EDF>,ở
```

I make the followings:

```
import pandas as pd
duong = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
code = pd.read_csv('viscii.csv')
code_dict = dict((a, b) for a, b in zip(code['key'],code[' value']))
duong.replace(code_dict, regex = True)
```

The results are:

```
    No                                             duong
0    1                               Ðu<U+1EDD>ng ÐT 605
1    2      Ðu<U+1EDD>ng Nam K<U+1EF3> Kh<U+1EDF>i Nghia
2    3                              Ðu<U+1EDD>ng Duy Tân
```

This is not what I want. What I want is:

```
No                                             duong
0    1                               Ðuờng ÐT 605
1    2                    Ðuờng Nam Kỳ Khởi Nghia
2    3                              Ðuờng Duy Tân
```

It means

```
<U+1EDD> is replaced by "ờ"
<U+1EF3> is replaced by "ỳ"
<U+1EDF> is replaced by "ở"
```

Can you please tell me what went wrong with this decoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72774693/843953) would work in your specific case, but the key here is that you want to *escape* your regex string, because you don't want it to consider the `+` as a special character.

Your answer works because enclosing the special character in `[...]` removes the special meaning, and regex interprets `[+]` as *any character in the group that is inside brackets*. A more general-purpose solution would be to use the [`re.escape` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape the regex when you create your dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

duong = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
code = pd.read_csv('viscii.csv')

code_dict = dict((re.escape(a), b) for a, b in zip(code['key'],code[' value']))
```

This creates a dictionary that looks like so:

```
{'<U\\+1EDD>': 'ờ', '<U\\+1EF3>': 'ỳ', '<U\\+1EDF>': 'ở'}
```

Notice the backslash in the keys before the `+`: `re.escape` knows that a bare `+` is a special character, so it escaped it for us. Now, when you do

```
duong.replace(code_dict, regex=True)
```

you get:

```
   No                     duong
0   1              Ðuờng ÐT 605
1   2   Ðuờng Nam Kỳ Khởi Nghia
2   3             Ðuờng Duy Tân
```

Comment: Very comprehensive response. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my mistake.

RegEx confused with '+', so I replaced '+' with '[+]'.

The code is

```
code = pd.read_csv('viscii.csv')
code['key'] = code["key"].str.replace("+", "[+]", regex = True)
code_dict = dict((a, b) for a, b in zip(code['key'],code[' value']))
duong.replace(code_dict, regex = True)
```

And then things went well